# Constructing a network-graph using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to construct the following image in LaTeX, but I'm not sure how to do it:

[image]

EDIT:

```
\begin{example} Consider the graph $G$ following shown in figure 1.2. The transition matrix of a simple random walk $G$ is 

\begin{equation*}
P =
\begin{bmatrix}[1.25]
    0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
    0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}


\begin{tikzpicture}[bn/.style={circle,fill,draw,text=white,font=\sffamily,minimum
size=1mm},every node/.append style={bn}]
 \path node (1) {1} -- ++ (50:2.5) node (2) {2} -- ++(-95:1.75) node (3) {3}
 -- ++(-85:1.75) node (4) {4} -- ++(40:2.75) node (5) {5}
 -- ++ (0,1.75) node (6) {6} ;
 \draw[thick] (1)--(2)--(6)--(5)--(4)--(1)--(3)--(5)--(2)--(3)--(4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{example}
```

of course the latter part of the code is what was provided in the answer. how would I centre this and put a caption?

Edit: I have fixed it by centred it but unable to put a caption

Comment: Hi. Note that today there are so many questions closed for being just-do-it-for-me questions. Your question is currently a just-do-it-for-me. You can change it so that people will help you by adding a MWE! A hint: you can use `\node` to draw nodes and `\draw` for the edges.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a site for do-it-for-me type of questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bn/.style={circle,fill,draw,text=white,font=\sffamily,minimum
size=9mm},every node/.append style={bn}]
 \path node (1) {1} -- ++ (50:2.5) node (2) {2} -- ++(-95:1.75) node (3) {3}
 -- ++(-85:1.75) node (4) {4} -- ++(40:2.75) node (5) {5}
 -- ++ (0,1.75) node (6) {6} ;
 \draw[thick] foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,...,6} {(\Y) -- (\X)}
 (6) -- (2) (2) -- (5) (3) -- (5) (1) -- (4) (1) -- (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your additional request: here is how one can center this in a figure. I implemented the great suggestions by Vinzza and Joule V.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[bn/.style={circle,fill,draw,text=white,font=\sffamily,minimum
size=9mm},every node/.append style={bn}]
 \path node (1) {1} -- ++ (50:2.5) node (2) {2} -- ++(-95:1.75) node (3) {3}
 -- ++(-85:1.75) node (4) {4} -- ++(40:2.75) node (5) {5}
 -- ++ (0,1.75) node (6) {6} ;
 \draw[thick] (1)--(2)--(6)--(5)--(4)--(1)--(3)--(5)--(2)--(3)--(4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A figure with major credits going to Vinzza and Joule V.}
\label{fig:VJVM}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like how you left one edge out! ^^

Comment: @Vinzza Yes, thanks! (That's why I wrote "a start" ;-)

Comment: @marmot (+1) The last `\draw` command can be improved to `\draw[thick] (1)--(2)--(6)--(5)--(4)--(1)--(3)--(5)--(2)--(3)--(4);`, I think.

Comment: how would I centre this and add a caption?

Comment: @marmot thank you for the additional part, I indeed appreciate your help :)