# Constructing a network graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I saw this question [Constructing a network-graph using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477302/constructing-a-network-graph-using-tikz), which is nice however I want my numbers outside the 'circles'.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bn/.style={circle,fill,font=\sffamily,minimum
size=2mm,node contents={},label=#1}]
 \path node(1) [bn=1]  -- ++ (50:2.5) node (2) [bn=2]  -- ++(-95:1.75) 
 node (3) [bn=above right:3] 
 -- ++(-85:1.75) node (4) [bn=below:4]  -- ++(40:2.75) node (5) [bn=below right:5] 
 -- ++ (0,1.75) node (6) [bn=6]  ;
 \draw[thick] (1)--(2)--(6)--(5)--(4)--(1)--(3)--(5)--(2)--(3)--(4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot  :)